# Something wrong with the xpath to a table in a page

Tags: python-2.7, xpath, scrapy

I am trying to scrape a webpage which has a table in it. I am trying to get the text of a `td` element. 
This is the [URL](http://farmer.gov.in/fpdrpt.aspx?dealertype=F) i am trying to scrape.

This is the `xpath` i gave which has the `table` in it:

```
//*[@id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_GridView1"]/tbody
```

And i am looping in it as:

```
for item in response.xpath('//[@id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_GridView1"]/tbody'):
        print item.xpath('//tr[2]/td[2]/text()').extract()
```

This is the code i have written for now by the way.

```
import scrapy

class FarmerSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "farmer"
    start_urls = [
        "http://farmer.gov.in/fpdrpt.aspx?dealertype=F",
    ]

    def parse(self, response):
        for item in response.xpath('//*[@id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_GridView1"]/tbody'):
            print item.xpath('//tr[2]/td[2]/text()').extract()
```

And, when i run the crawler, it doesn't return anything. I know i am doing wrong with selecting the `xpath`.
If this step works, i will further go to fetch more fields. 
Please, let me know if it's off-topic or already answered before downvoting. :)
I already  checked many answered questions but none of them helped completely.

Comment: Are you sure the tbody is actually in the source? That is often added by the browser

Comment: Padraic Cunningham I checked in chrome console. And it's there. I see in a few answers that when they removed tbody , it worked. i tried that but i still didn't get any result.

Comment: What you see in Chrome console is not necessarily what you get back as source, also how many tbody tags do you actually see?

Comment: As @PadraicCunningham  suggested, check the raw source of the HTML page (as in `view-source:http://farmer.gov.in/fpdrpt.aspx?dealertype=F`), the `tbody` is not there. Also, you're using an absolute XPath expression in your loop, try using a relative one `print item.xpath('.//tr[2]/td[2]/text()').extract()`

Comment: @PadraicCunningham I see only one tbody under the xpath i gave as parent. You are right. I tried removing tbody but still couldn't come close the proper xpath.

Comment: @paultrmbrth yeah. silly me. I just checked the raw HTML and i don't see any tbody there. tbody automatically gets generated with the tables if i am not wrong.

Comment: Then you don't need a loop, just incorporate Paul's suggestion into a single xpath.

Comment: So, should this be my `xpath` paul suggested?
`print response.xpath('//table[@id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_GridView1"]//tr[2]/td[2]/text()').extract()`

Comment: @PadraicCunningham that suggested solution works when i don't use `text()` and i can see all the different tags along with the value i wanna fetch. But when i use `text()`, it doesn't work. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Ok. I ended up using BeautifulSoup to parse the content and everything became easier. Thanks for the help guys.